# "Cognifide.PowerShell.SitecoreIntegrations.Applications.PowerShellConsole,Cognifide.PowerShell" not found Error while opening Sitecore PowerShell

Tags: powershell-extensions

When we try to open Sitecore Powershell console or ISE after fresh installation on one of the Sitecore instances, we receive below error :

[image]

Log Entry for this error is:

```
3572 06:48:51 WARN Could not find type in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Cognifide.PowerShell.SitecoreIntegrations.Applications.PowerShellConsole
3572 06:48:51 ERROR CodeBeside class "Cognifide.PowerShell.SitecoreIntegrations.Applications.PowerShellConsole,Cognifide.PowerShell" not found. (method: Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.OnInit(EventArgs e)).
```

Sitecore version : 8.1 Update 1 & Powershell Version 3.3

Comment: 1) Please edit your post and include errors as text, not as pictures. 2) Have you checked that `Cognifide.PowerShell.dll` is present in the site's `bin` folder? 3) Have you tried reinstalling SPE?

Comment: we have the cognifide*.dll  & config files. I haven't tried reinstalling let me try.

Comment: You already had this issue last year: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/7/t/3039 A reinstall helped you that time.

Comment: it was in less priority environment where i had full control but at this evn i hav limited access & cannot dig into more. Admin seeking some technical info behind this :(

Comment: I got the root cause for this issue. :)
As we are aware ( + mentioned in the answer) there is a conflict in powershell
version between installed & deployed. 
RootCause: we have initially installed sitecore PS version of 3.3 but 
unfortunately dev team-A has added old powershell version (2.8) in their web project.
Hence after each deployment, we were able to see this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be different factors that causing this issue:

**1. Version Compatibility**

- SPE version is not compatible with the Sitecore version.
- Powershell version should be in sync across all the environment if development
  code base is having powershell dll reference.

**2. Package Installation**

- The package is not installing properly whereby some files are not getting installed accordingly.

I will tend to go for the 2nd point since the error shows that it cannot create an object from 
`Cognifide.PowerShell.SitecoreIntegrations.Applications.PowerShellConsole,Cognifide.PowerShell`.

Seems like the assembly `Cognifide.PowerShell` is not properly installed. Try to make sure that the proper security permission (write/read) is set on the website folder including subfolders.